# Access Current Obj inside an Array.contains Method

Tags: ios, swift

I have created the below code which cycles through an `array` with the `.foreach` method then has a separate `array.contains` method inside it that it performs on a different array (`myArray`). I am wanting to know how inside the `array.contains` method can I reference the current element in the cycle inside `myArray`.

```
var myArray = [Struct]

  models.forEach({ (currentModel: Model) in

    if myArray.contains(where: {$0.value == currentModel.value}) {

    // Want to change the current object in Array
    let myArray[currentElement].value = 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the found item in `myArray` you have to get its `index` because `myArray` is value type

```
var myArray = [Struct]

models.forEach({ currentModel in
   if let index = myArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.value == currentModel.value}) {
      myArray[index].value = //
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful-

```
var myArray = [Struct]

var i = 0
for item in myArray {
    if item.value == currentModel.value {
        var currentElement = item
        currentElement.value = "new Value"
        let myArray[i].value = currentElement
        i += 1
    }
}
```